# Basic circle physics collision logic

Tags: math, collision-detection, physics

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/12571073/#editor

At the least the basic logic behind the reflection-collision

Thanks.

This is my attempt in swift, but any languages are welcome.

```
let entranceAngle = atan2(projectile.force.dy, projectile.force.dx)
let radius = distance(projectile.position, bubble.position)
let power = distance(dx: projectile.force.dx, dy: projectile.force.dy)
let pivotAngle = asin((projectile.position.y - bubble.position.y) / radius)
let exitAngle = 2 * pivotAngle - entranceAngle

projectile.applyForce(CGVector(
    dx: power * cos(exitAngle),
    dy: power * sin(exitAngle)))
```

Comment: It's just reflecting the collision across the normal.

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to do that, because my attempt to do that does not seem to work properly.

Comment: how can i calculate the normal vector? I think vector - 2 * Dot(vector, normal) * normal would give me the resulting vector

Comment: The normal vector extends from the center of the circle to the point of impact.

Comment: so normal_x  = acos(Cy-cy/Cx-cx), normal_y = asin(Cy-cy/Cx-cx) ? That doesn't seem right

Comment: each component times the radius

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, for whoever this might help:

```
let normalVector = CGVector(
    dx: projectile.position.x - bubble.position.x,
    dy: projectile.position.y - bubble.position.y).normalized
let dotProduct =
    normalVector.dx * projectile.force.dx +
    normalVector.dy * projectile.force.dy
let resultingForce =
    projectile.force - 2 * dotProduct * normalVector
```